# How a peer to peer (P2P) socket connection is established in general, in the context of WebRTC?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, webrtc, p2p

Conceptually I am unable to comprehend that how 2 devices, which are connected to their respective Wifi networks (for example) are able to establish a peer to peer connection, even with intermediate temporary server in between.

E.g. Computer A's public IP is 1.1.1.1 & private IP is 192.x.x.x. Computer B's public IP is 2.2.2.2 & private IP is 192.y.y.y. Without any firewall etc. (general case), **how will they make a direct socket connection among them?**
Will appreciate if you can explain in slightly layman's term.

---

**Context**: I am studying a server, which intends to provide WebRTC in the browser. Using Google's STUN server, they are able to exchange media in many cases. But conceptually I am unclear, on what takes place in between.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does WebRTC work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708252/how-does-webrtc-work)

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC uses a process called ICE for establishing the connection. Its a suite of techniques for NAT holepunching that mostly rely on the STUN protocol.
The formal description is in [RFC 5245](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245) (updated by a newer version)

[This presentation from the IETF 92](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/17mVv6_eKqLkKkG-pwx_p-NOrYl2CK02OAtAtcHKJgHU/edit#slide=id.p63) is one of the best slide decks I've seen so far.